# Angular2 Form control not on form.controls collection when using formControl directive with ngControl

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I'm using Angular2 rc4 with the new forms. If I use `ngControl` and name attributes on my input and then look on the form, I will see the control in the `form.controls` collection.

```
<form #programForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" ngControl="showTitle"  name="showTitle" class="form-control" aria-describedby="ShowTitle" placeholder="Show Title" [(ngModel)]="criteria.programFilter.name"  />        
</form>
```

Then in some event I'll call a method on the component class passing in the form and then view the form controls.

```
someMethod(form: NgForm){
    for (let c in form.controls) {
        let ctrl = form.controls[c];
        if (ctrl != null) {  //we will have the control here
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

If I then add a `[formControl]` directive to the input, the `form.controls` collection no longer has the control.

```
<input type="text" ngControl="showTitle"  name="showTitle" [formControl]="showTitleCtrl" class="form-control" aria-describedby="ShowTitle" placeholder="Show Title" [(ngModel)]="criteria.programFilter.name"  />

someMethod(form: NgForm){
    for (let c in form.controls) {
        let ctrl = form.controls[c];
        if (ctrl != null) {  //we won't have the control here
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

I need to have the control in the `form.controls` collection and I need to be able subscribe to the input value changes.

```
showTitleCtrl = new FormControl();
this.showTitleCtrl.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(v => this.doSomething());
```

In the deprecated forms this all worked correctly having `ngControl="showTitle"` and `[ngFormControl]="showTitleCtrl"`